# How to correctly setup npm onchange scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, sass

I'm trying to create a basic npm script to build my personal web projects, basically want to compile and minify Sass and JS ES6+ code. I'm new to npm scripts, but below is what I managed to do with the resources I found.

This is what I have so far:

```json
"scripts": {
    "devserver": "live-server --open=/dist/",
    "sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o scss/ dist/css/ -w",
    "terser": "terser src/js/index.js -c -m -o dist/js/index.js",
    "watch:sass": "onchange 'scss/*.scss' -- npm run sass",
    "watch:js": "onchange 'js/*.js' -- npm run terser",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel devserver watch:*"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2",
    "terser": "^5.3.0"
}
```

Couple of things I notice:

1. When I do `npm run start` the live server kicks in and loads the site and when I change the js or scss code the script register the changes but these are not reflected in the `dist/` folder
2. Only when I run say `npm run sass` or `npm run terser` the changes do happen inside the `dist/` folder

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using *Windows* system? BTW - You can simply run `npm start` with the `run` part (`start` is a "special" command).

Comment: @vsync I'm using Mac Catalina

Comment: Try switching from `npm-run-all` to [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)